# nopCommerce Bulk Insertion in Import using excel issue with Foreign Key

Tags: nopcommerce, bulk, insertion

The Insert statement conflicted with the foreign key 'ProductXXXXX'. The Conflict occurred in Database 'DatabaseName', table "dbo.TableName", column 'ColumnName'
[image]
The Statement has been terminated.

**[strong text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOz4V.png)**

Comment: The problem occurs when you are trying to insert a record with a value in the foreign key column that doesn't exist in the parent table. May be your mapping data is wrong in excel.